# Passing vector of vectors to function

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

I have a function which accepts a

```
vector<vector<MyClass>>
```

and modifies the MyClass instances. It's been a long time since I've written any C++ and I'm having difficulty remembering what is sufficient here for passing the entire arg by reference instead of by value.

My original method signature was:

```
void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass> > vec) { ... }
```

I want to make this memory efficient so I originally changed this to:

```
void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*> > vec) { ... }
```

Then I realized that this would mean that my vec value would still make copies of all the inner vectors. So I changed my function signature to:

```
void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*> >* vec) { ... }
```

Is this sufficient, or do I also need to do something like:

```
void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*>* >* vec) { ... }
```

Could someone highlight the memory differences between all of these? Thanks a lot!

Comment: why dont you just take reference to the vector of vectors? No memory leaks that way

Comment: Using typedef might make it clearer

Comment: if using modern c++ then a `using` would be even better :)

Answer (score 17):

Simply

```
void modifyVectorOfVectors( vector< vector< MyClass > >& vec) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass> > vec) { ... }`
   Copy  external vector which has all elements of inner vector
2. `void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*> > vec) { ... }`
   Copy external vector which has all inner vectors  which holds all pointers of MyClass
3. `void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*>* > vec) { ... }`
   Copy external vector which has all pointers of inner vectors and  and inner vectors holds pointers of MyClass
4. `void modifyVectorOfVectors(vector<vector<MyClass*> *> vec*) { ... }`
   Copy pointer of external vector which has all pointers of inner vectors and  and inner vectors holds pointers of MyClass